# Pass a variable to form

Tags: javascript, html

How do I pass a variable (imageX) in javascript to my HTML form's hidden field?

```
<div class="popup">
    <form action="myphp.php" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="location">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

js

```
var imageX = 'www.myweb.com/images/'+image+'.jpg';
```

Comment: Can you please tell me from where are you getting image variable value? Is is an event or something or its just assigned when the page loads.

Comment: keep some id to your form and do this: 
`document.getElementById('formId').location.value = imageX;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give an id attribute to you hidden field...

```
<input type="hidden" name="location" id="location">
```

then set the value of that attribute as the imageX value using javascript.

```
var imageX = 'www.myweb.com/images/'+image+'.jpg';
document.getElementById("location").value=imageX;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.forms[0].location.value = imageX;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a id for your hidden input, say `id="imagePath"`

```
 <input type="hidden" name="location" id="imagePath">
```

Now use javascript as below,

```
var imageX = 'www.myweb.com/images/'+image+'.jpg';
document.getElementById("imagePath").value = imageX;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.forms[0].elements["location"].value = imageX;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can attach onclick event and call a js function to assign value to the hidden input

HTML:

```
<div class="popup">
        <form action="myphp.php" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="location">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick='passImg();'>
       </form>
       </div>
```

js:

```
function passImg(){
var imageX = 'www.myweb.com/images/'+image+'.jpg';
var a= $('[name="location"]').val(imageX);
}
```